# Are there still the settings for the arguments passed to a view?

Tags: 7, views

Views 2 for Drupal 6 had settings for the arguments passed to a view.
Does Views 3 for Drupal 7 still have those settings?

This is [the partial screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjdp0.png) that I see when I edit the taxonomy term view (the screenshot appears blur because I resized it to 70% of its original dimensions).

If this makes any difference, the screenshot is for the development snapshot of Views (7.x-3.x-dev), used together the development snapshot of Chaos Tools (7.x-1.x-dev).

[image: Front page (Content)]

Comment: I haven't taken the new views UI out for a test drive yet, but I imagine we all are going to use a bit of time to adjust.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument settings have not been removed; they have been renamed, and in the actual development snapshot they are called *Contextual Filters*.

Comment: Is there a summary of the changes for the new views ui anywhere?

Comment: As Bojan Zivanovic suggested, http://www.angrydonuts.com/views-for-drupal-7-enters-a-new-era reports the main changes for Views in Drupal 7. The article has been written from the main maintainer of Views, merlinofchaos.